# LEFT JOIN table B with count of rows of table C

Tags: mysql, count, left-join

There are 3 tables: `table_A{id, table_b_id, table_c_id}`, `table_B{id,..}` and `table_C{id}`

I am using left join to get all of A's, joined with table_B.id.

What i need is to add a count of items from table_C.
I prefer not to do it with subquery, is it possible?

The query:

```
SELECT table_A.*
    FROM table_A
LEFT JOIN table_B
    ON table_B.id = table_A.table_b_id
WHERE table_A.{field} = {condition}
GROUP BY table_A.{some_field}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT table_A.*,
       COUNT(table_C.id) count_of_c
    FROM table_A
LEFT JOIN table_B
    ON table_B.id = table_A.table_b_id
LEFT JOIN table_C
    ON table_C.id = table_A.table_c_id
WHERE table_A.{field} = {condition}
GROUP BY table_A.{some_field}
```

On a side note: Although MySql `GROUP BY` extensions allows you to put columns in `SELECT` that are not part of `GROUP BY` don't do it since there is no way to tell which row to pick in a group. Therefore your `SELECT` clause should look like

```
table_A.{some_field}, <Aggregate function>(table_A.{other_field})...
```

or you have to join results of aggregation with table_A.